# Identical Tuples are not Equals?

Tags: typescript

Sometimes on operation on `Tuples` we end up transforming `[a: 1, b?: 2]` to a form like `[a: 1, b?: 2 | undefined]`

While it doesn't alter anything it reads poorly so I ended up with this type (given `Cast` which is in the playground and simply ensures what is passed is a `ReadonlyArray`)

```
// Given UnNullify that transforms [a: 1, b?: 2 | undefined] -> [a: 1, b?: 2]
type UnNullify <Data extends ReadonlyArray <any>> = Cast <{
  [K in keyof Data]: Exclude <Data [K], null | undefined>
}, ReadonlyArray <any>>
```

What I do not understand is while the type is computed correctly it is no longer `Equals` to the original type (`Equals` test for equality type is in the playground)

```
type T = UnNullify <[a: 1, b?: 2 | undefined]> // [a: 1, b?: 2]
type Test1 = Equals <T, [a: 1, b?: 2]> // false ?? - how come
type Test2 = Equals <[a: 1, b?: 2], [a: 1, b?: 2]> // true as expected
```

Is they're is a reason for that ? how to overcome it ?

[link to playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3X12W)

Edit [link to bug request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50753)

Comment: This `Equals` type does not do what you want. I suggest defining it instead as `type Equals<A, B> = [A, B] extends [B, A] ? true : false`. This doesn't *quite* mean "equals" - it only checks that the two types are assignable to each other - but in most situations that is really what you want to check anyway.

Comment: @kaya3 equals as designed is for testing strict equality and it is was is intended here
The question remains: how come to type identical (as represented exactly the same way by the compiler) differs in equality ?

Comment: @kaya3 Did test it with you're type (named it `Identical`)  it produces the same inconsistency [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXj4Dm)

Comment: That is surprising, and looks like a bug in the compiler - here is a simplified version which demonstrates the issue. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgOQK4BsUEsBmIA8AVKCAD2AjgBMBnKAJwgENyB7OFEKJOAaziYHc4AbQC6APigBeKAG8AsACgoUQQGko6OFC4QQTTFDzCAXFACiRAMYok5CPlXCANFDioUUAD4cKETBojkogoAvgoKoJBQAGJMTJKwiG5YuIL0JgCMzgBGAPwmAEye3rZ+cAFiCgD0lUpQAHo5YfIR0HgQlMDxqRnZeVD5woQkZFTRsVA5UMA0SNAmmPQolBBVNUoNCkA)

Comment: Should I open a bug in typescript github ? (not too much experienced here ^^)

Comment: I didn't find an existing issue that matches this one, so I suggest reporting it, yes.

Comment: Posted a [bug request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50753)